# how to prove a mapping is continious

Tags: real-analysis

how do i prove a given mapping is continuous

say x ---> x+x0 for x0 fixed.

how about inverse?

i feel this is obvious since this is like g(x) = x+5 which is obviously continuous but i'm not sure how one would approach a formal proof. How about one for inverse mapping?

on second thought: since g'(x) is defined, g(x) is continuous. also i suppose i could make epsilon-delta approach?

Comment: How about starting from the definition of continuous mapping?

Comment: There are several ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $t\in\mathbb R$. Take $\delta=\varepsilon$ and so, if $|x-t|<\delta$, then 
$$|f(x)-f(t)|=|x-t|<\varepsilon$$
there for the function is continuous for all $t\in\mathbb R$, therefore $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$.